# How do I cast the results from valueForKey into the correct types in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to get the value of a variable (passed as a string) in my class and have it casted correctly. This is what I have so far.

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class Test: NSObject {
    var stringVar = "Some String"
    var arrayVar = ["Some", "Array"]

    override init() {
        super.init()

        var dynamicKey = "stringVar"
        var valueForKeyResult1: AnyObject! = valueForKey(dynamicKey)

        dynamicKey = "arrayVar"
        var valueForKeyResult2: AnyObject! = valueForKey(dynamicKey)

        var someVarName = valueForKeyResult2
    }
}

Test()
```

Now how do I get the var valueForKeyResult 1 & 2 casted into the types that they were in the first place (without knowing what types they were)?

Comment: Depends on what types you want. Want an integer? String has a toInt() function. Want something else?

Comment: Well, I want the someVarName filled with the array. The problem is I don't know beforehand what type it will be. In this playground it's an Array, but the code I'm writing will not know that beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

They are already the correct types:

```
class Test: NSObject {
    var stringVar = "Some String"
    var arrayVar = ["Some", "Array"]

    override init() {
        super.init()

        var dynamicKey = "stringVar"
        var valueForKeyResult1: AnyObject! = valueForKey(dynamicKey)
        println("valueForKeyResult1: \(NSStringFromClass(valueForKeyResult1?.dynamicType)), value: \(valueForKeyResult1!)\n")

        dynamicKey = "arrayVar"
        var valueForKeyResult2: AnyObject! = valueForKey(dynamicKey)
        println("valueForKeyResult2: \(NSStringFromClass(valueForKeyResult2?.dynamicType)), value: \(valueForKeyResult2!)\n")
    }
}

Test()
```

Output:

> valueForKeyResult1: Swift._NSContiguousString, value: Some String
>
> valueForKeyResult2: _TtCSs23_ContiguousArrayStorage000000010050D510, value: (
>       Some,
>       Array
>   )

Comment: So how do I put these values in another var with the correct type (without knowing the correct type beforehand? So I want the type of someVarName in below result to be an Array: var someVarName = valueForKeyResult2